# POSIX shell scripts shebang #!/bin/sh vs #!/usr/bin/env sh, any difference?

Tags: shell, posix, shebang

I recently noticed that many scripts are using `/usr/bin/env` in their [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). I have seen that mainly using [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) and [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), but thus far never in conjunction with [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) `sh` (`ash`, `dash`,...).

I wonder why, and if my, meant-to-be highly portable, [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell scripts might benefit from the `env` approach?

---

Is there a general concensus on whether to use:

- standard:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  ```
- environment:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env sh
  ```

---

Let me stress this enough:

**I never have seen this with `sh`.**

Comment: On macOS, for example, `/bin/bash` is an antiquated POC, but one can get newer bash via homebrew. So I use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if write a script for both my MBP and my Linux PC. But if I'm going to stick to POSIX, then `/bin/sh` is fine for both; I don't see much of a use case except in some outdated system where `/bin/sh` might not be a POSIX shell, in which case I doubt `/usr/bin/env` will work either.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77586/70524: "There are two programs whose location you can rely on on almost every unix variant: `/bin/sh` and `/usr/bin/env`. Some obscure and mostly retired Unix variants had `/bin/env` without having `/usr/bin/env`, but you're unlikely to encounter them. Modern systems have `/usr/bin/env` precisely because of its widespread use in shebangs. `/usr/bin/env` is something you can count on."

Comment: "There are two programs whose location you can rely on on almost every unix variant: `/bin/sh` and `/usr/bin/env`" except that neither path is standard and the most used unix variant ever (like >99% of existing installations) doesn't have either of them.

Comment: @muru FYI POSIX doesn't say anything about either `/bin/sh` or shebang-ed scripts. Both are non-standard extensions.

Comment: @mosvy Which most used unix variant ever doesn't have /bin/sh?

Comment: @OskarSkog didn't some Solaris have the Bourne shell for `/bin/sh` and an actual POSIX sh somewhere else?

Comment: A unix variant based on the Linux kernel, which is also the most used operating system, period, not just the most used unix variant. And despite preconceived notions, it is a regular Unix system, more similar to eg. Ubuntu or FreeBSD 12 than those are to Unix version 7 or Sys III ;-)

Comment: Android? Really?  Does it by default have anything that resembles a unix-like userland?  I know I can install stuff, but does it have that by default?

Comment: @OskarSkog Yes. Really. Android is using a C library based on Open/NetBSD (rather than glibc or musl), base utilities based on toybox (rather than GNU coreutils or busybox) and the mksh shell (rather than dash or bash). Those may not all be the most felicitous choices, but they easily clear the "unix-like" criterium. Also notice that its "java" UI also builds on Linux interfaces and concepts (it does NOT run like a vm, only using the Linux kernel for low-level chores; apps map to unix user ids, selinux / capabilities / namespaces are used to contain them, etc, etc).

Comment: @muru be vary careful: a `bash` compiled with default parameters is not POSIX compliant, this is why Apple offers a special `bash` version in `/bin/sh` that e.g. treats `echo` correctly. BTW: `/bin/sh` is not part of POSIX. POSIX rather requires you to do: `export PATH=$(getconf PATH)` followed by `sh` to get a POSIX shell.

Comment: Never seen it with `#!/bin/sh`, because the POSIX standard mandates that `/bin/sh` is the standard (Bourne) shell.

Comment: @mosvy, which "99% of Unix installed" has no `/bin/sh`?! First off, that won't be able to get certified as Unix... And sorry, *no* Linux distribution has been certified as "Unix". Too much hassle for little gain.

Comment: @vonbrand __1.__ __POSIX does NOT mandate the existence of `/bin/sh`__. 2. Except for some obscure Chinese SUSE (or Centos?) fork(s) (iirc), no Linux system has ever been "certified" as Unix.

Comment: @mosvy.There are no Unix-certified OSes.  There are OSes that have the UNIX brand.

Comment: @mosvy Given that the use of a shebang is "unspecified" in POSIX:   **If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.** [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). It is highly irrelevant what POSIX say or doesn't say about `/bin/sh`. But, for the record, it does specify [in the APPLICATION USAGE od `sh`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_16) that the utility sh **must** be found with `command -v sh`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Setting to `#!/bin/sh` will go directly to that file `/bin/sh`.

Setting to `#!/usr/bin/env sh` will execute `/usr/bin/env` with an argument of `sh`.  This will cause the script to be executed by  `sh` in your `PATH` variable rather than explicitly with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: None of these commands will give you a POSIX shell in case your `PATH` is not the result from a `getconf PATH` call.

Comment: Nice Answer. It's a common doubt

Answer (score 0):

Many other posts (like the accepted answer of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164203/will-a-shell-script-execute-in-solaris-if-not-which-is-the-fastest-way-to-make)) mentioned that `bin/sh` in Solaris system (10 or older) is NOT a POSIX-compliant shell, instead, it is under `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh`.

In this case `#!/bin/sh` might not work properly if it meant to be POSIX-compliant. However, I doubt `#!/usr/bin/env sh` would point to the desired shell.